# How to make good database design?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I need to design a database of statistics.

I have User who has its own statistics and have data for every 30 minutes per day, like:

**Time   | Data**

10:44 | Some data

11:13 | Another data

11:43 | Data example

...

23:32 | Data example

For example, I want to get all data on 21 Apr 2017, so I will get all those fields according to 21 Apr 2017.

The question is - How to correctly design database for such case?

This picture shows db to which I came up.

[image]

Comment: There's no *Time* part in your schema.

Comment: You don't want separate tables for Year, Month and Day. That is a nightmare to deal with. You should have a column with datetime as the datatype. And you really shouldn't name your primary key Id in every table. Column names should not change based on which table they are in. A UserID is always a UserID. It shouldn't magically just be ID because it is in the User table.

Comment: You need just two tables `Users` and `Data`

Comment: @Fliburt, image updated, thnx )

Comment: There is no reason for splitting the date into several tables. With the same reasoning you could split the year into millennium, century, decade and single year and make this four tables, or a name into first letter, second letter, and so on and end up with fifty tables or how many letters ever you want to allow for a name. It just makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use two tables:

```
User:
    id (PK), name
    unique index (name)

Data:
    id (PK), user_id (FK), date (YYYY-MM-DD), time (HH:MM:SS), data

    index (user_id, date)
```

With such design you will be able to retrieve data for any particular date for any user quite quickly.

Comment: Why not have date and time as a single datetime field?

Comment: @JohnRC because OP needs to get all records for the date, not by date-time, so index on date only could be more efficient

Comment: OK, then how about a datetime column with a computed column for the date, which could be indexed? I think that's cleaner from a schema viewpoint.

Comment: @JohnRC it is duplication and de-normalization, it could be done sometimes though

Answer (score 2):

This looks very complicated. I'd expect:

- **table user** (*user_id*, name)
- **table user_statistic** (*user_id, datetime*, data)

(Primary keys are italic.)